# How do I add the Varnish-Cache signature to an HTTP request in VCL?

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

I would like to add the Varnish-Cache version/signature to my incoming HTTP requests so I can log the Varnish version with requests on my webserver.  I understand this information is available in `obj.http.Server`, but this doesn't work inside `vcl_recv` or `vcl_miss`:

`set req.http.X-VARNISH-VERSION = obj.http.Server;`

Apparently those vcl subs only have access to `req` and not `obj`.  Is there any other way to get the version number into an HTTP request header?

I am using Varnish 3.0.2.

[Edit]
I am using a Varnish module as an integral component in my system and as part of my automated testing I am running functional tests through the load balancer.  I want my web servers (hhvm i this case) to know what version of Varnish is proxying the requests.  Currently I am using a hardcoded string for this purpose, but I would like to automate this so I can distribute a non-hardcoded configuration to my varnish servers.

Answer (score 0):

Varnish only sets the Server header when performing a synthetic response (like in `vcl_error`) and the header in that case doesn't contains Varnish' version.

Please extend your question, I can't envision what you want to achieve with that (and why a fixed string header substitution won't feet your needs).

Comment: I've added more info, but please note that I'm altering the request for the sake of my downstream servers, not the response to the client.

Comment: It might be available using inline C (search the code for version string)